# How to link .doc files with LibreOffice Writer

Tags: debian, kde, libreoffice

I received a .doc file in IceDove, double-clicked it and it asks if I want to save/open it, the only option for opening is caligraauthor. I want to use LibreOffice Writer for these documents, but when I choose 'other', it asks me to select the file (standard file selection dialogue).

Which LibreOffice Writer 'file' do I need to specify in this dialogue box? I've done a`find / -name '*writer*'` and '*libreoffice*', but there are hundreds of files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file can lunch Writer, with option `--writer`: `/usr/bin/libreoffice`, which link to `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice`.

However, you might want to config MIME type for `.doc` files, called `application/msword`, follow the instruction discussed [here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=88210).

Comment: Great, I just needed to find `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice` in the file dialogue and it works perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: `type libreoffice` will tell you that libreoffice is in `/usr/bin/libreoffice`. `ls -l /usr/bin/libreoffice` will show that this is a link to `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice`, but do not use the one in `/usr/lib` directly this is just how it is implemented, and may change.